# Notepad++: Ctrl-S does not Save, instead inserts [DC3]; Ctrl-F inserts [ACK]

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, keymap

I've been using Notepad++ more as my primary code editor. Just a few minutes ago, however, I accidentally pressed some combination of keys (no idea what I pressed) and suddenly my standard shortcut keys no longer work.

When I press Ctrl-S, it doesn't save my document; instead it inserts this funky little "DC3" character (looks like a rounded black rectangle with white text inside). When I press Ctrl-F (the Find key) I get a similar "ACK" symbol.

The only answer I've found on the web has to do with changing your shortcut key mappings; however my shortcut key mappings have NOT CHANGED at all, they are still set as they should be, with Ctrl-S mapping to "Save" and Ctrl-F mapping to "Find..".

I've clearly switched to some bizarre alternate key mode, but I have no idea what that might be or how to get rid of it.

**Update:** I've played around a bit more to see what other shortcuts are broken. So far, they all seem to be, except for the Windows standard ones like "Ctrl-X" and "Ctrl-V". Here's a sampling:

```
KEY             Should Do:            Current Behavior:

Ctrl-Tab        Cycle open tabs       <does nothing>
Ctrl-W          Close current tab     [ETB]
Ctrl-N          Open New tab          [SO]
Ctrl-O          File Open window      [SI]
Ctrl-A          Select All            [DC3]
Ctrl-Z          Undo                  <Works as expected>
Ctrl-C          Copy selection        <Works as expected>
Ctrl-U          Make lowercase        [NAK]
```

Comment: (By the way, the symbols are abbreviations of the [ASCII control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#cite_ref-33).)

Comment: I think it's an notepad++ runtime error. I've met the same pb as yours serveral minutes ago, and it works correctly now.

Comment: I face this today. I closed the file where I have run replace all and then restarting resolve the issue.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Ok, this is pretty pathetic. But it's possible some other moron could run into this issue so I feel justified in posting.

A few minutes ago I did a "Replace all" in my current document. Apparently, the dialog window informing me that "# occurrences were replaced" was hidden under another window, so I never closed it.

And apparently, when that little window remains open, pressing shortcut keys with the main editor window in focus causes those funky results.

It's strange behavior, to be sure, but it's still a pretty newb-ish scenario. Ah well.

Comment: Does this mean you didn't try restarting the software? :P

Comment: +1 Thanks! This is actually quite easy to do... to get a dialog or small prompt stuck behind the main window, since they aren't modal. eg. Ctrl+F and search for 'raspberry' - a small postage stamp sized non-modal prompt appears "Can't find the text...". Click back in the Find dialog (perhaps by mistake) without responding to the prompt and the small prompt vanishes to the back and remains open. Close the Find dialog; small prompt remains open.

Comment: +1, Totally worth posting. This just happened to me a minute ago. The "ACK" char was certainly not what I expected.

Comment: Had some stupid dialog boxes hiding behind the editor window. Clicked OK to close them and Ctrl+C works agian. Thanks!

Comment: Funky - Monkeys, Jungle Jump...

Comment: Ha, I saw this as well when trying to install a large number of plugins (that ended up taking forever to fail due to bad proxy settings).

Comment: i just experienced the same thing with ACK being inserted on Ctrl-
F. I installed SherloXplorer (very nice plugin), but did not re-start Notepad++. It was fixed after re-starting.

Comment: I ran into this issue with version 7.5.7, but the above solution did not apply (no dialog box was open).  To fix: I closed all open files, closed NPP, reopened, typed a few characters into the blank document, and hit CTRL+ALT+S to "Save as...".

Comment: I recently had this issue with a crashing plugin (DSpellCheck I think, when opening a curl response containing a gzipped body). The crash pop-up was displayed several times and one of them stayed behind the main window (I think after I moved to something else). I am not able to reproduce the issue any more though (the plugin does not crash). Anyway, was the issue [reported](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues)? I don't find it.

Comment: In my case, there was not child open, but restarting the `notepad++`, solved situation.

Comment: I had a dialogue windows open behind the main window, resulting in the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the language bar. It's possible you set the language or keyboard differently for that application.

Do any other applications have this issue?

Comment: I checked in Notepad and a few other text apps, as well as my IM program. The shortcuts behave as expected. All other settings appear to be the same. Good ideas though! Thanks.

Comment: Language bar in Windows can be per-application.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just now caused by a different problem.

**Make sure your file is not set to read-only**. :)

Answer (score 0):

As an addon to Brian's answer:

## Old Notepad++ bug when you have any popups open

This seems to be an old bug inside Notepad++

The first report I found was from 2010:
https://notepad-plus-plus.narkive.com/R7BQacOI/notepad-ctrl-s-no-longer-saves-file-and-instead-inserts-dc3-control-character , https://archive.is/wip/oROp0

Here is a video demo with solution from 2016:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTcoMa19huY , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTcoMa19huY

Here is a thread on the NPP forums from 2018:
https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15803/notepad-7-5-6-inserts-ascii-control-codes-like-dc3-for-control-s-without-any-background-dialogues-open-when-unix-lf-utf-8-w-o-bom-format-is-used , https://archive.is/J3xbk

I found two bug reports that mention "DC3". Unfortunately none of them ended up fixing anything.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnotepad-plus-plus%2Fnotepad-plus-plus%2Fissues+dc3

  - https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2818 Error Dialog disables keyboard shortcuts #2818
  - https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4067 MsgBox "Command Line Arguments" not on top #4067

And as for the Brian's table: I guess:
The ascii table (in hex) is here:

```
$ ascii -x
   00 NUL    10 DLE    20      30 0    40 @    50 P    60 `    70 p
   01 SOH    11 DC1    21 !    31 1    41 A    51 Q    61 a    71 q
   02 STX    12 DC2    22 "    32 2    42 B    52 R    62 b    72 r
   03 ETX    13 DC3    23 #    33 3    43 C    53 S    63 c    73 s
   04 EOT    14 DC4    24 $    34 4    44 D    54 T    64 d    74 t
   05 ENQ    15 NAK    25 %    35 5    45 E    55 U    65 e    75 u
   06 ACK    16 SYN    26 &    36 6    46 F    56 V    66 f    76 v
   07 BEL    17 ETB    27 '    37 7    47 G    57 W    67 g    77 w
   08 BS     18 CAN    28 (    38 8    48 H    58 X    68 h    78 x
   09 HT     19 EM     29 )    39 9    49 I    59 Y    69 i    79 y
   0A LF     1A SUB    2A *    3A :    4A J    5A Z    6A j    7A z
   0B VT     1B ESC    2B +    3B ;    4B K    5B [    6B k    7B {
   0C FF     1C FS     2C ,    3C <    4C L    5C \    6C l    7C |
   0D CR     1D GS     2D -    3D =    4D M    5D ]    6D m    7D }
   0E SO     1E RS     2E .    3E >    4E N    5E ^    6E n    7E ~
   0F SI     1F US     2F /    3F ?    4F O    5F _    6F o    7F DEL
```

And I think what happens when CTRL-W inserts "ETB" is that
ASCII "W" 0x57 loses 0x40 and turns into 0x17 ETB.

There seems to be a negative 0x40 (decimal 64) offset in all cases.

(Except CTRL-A but I think Brian may have mixed that up with CTRL-S instead. --
Brian's table maps CTRL-A to DC3
But all the other reports I have read map CTRL-S to DC3 instead.

```
KEY      Should Do:             Current Behavior:
         
Ctrl-Tab Cycle open tabs        <does nothing>
Ctrl-W   0x57 Close current tab 0x17 [ETB]
Ctrl-N   0x4E Open New tab      0x0E [SO]
Ctrl-O   0x4F File Open window  0x0F [SI]
Ctrl-A   Select All             0x13 [DC3]
Ctrl-Z   Undo                   <Works as expected>
Ctrl-C   Copy selection         <Works as expected>
Ctrl-U   0x55 Make lowercase    0x15 [NAK]
```

- https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/ascii/ascii.1.en.html

Details regarding the relationship between "CTRL-W", "^W", 0x17 and 0x57:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes